# How to open nested row of tab based on selection?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have these 3 row of tabs. First row has options Construction and Interior. On clicking construction it should open the row of tabs with id as construction and make interiors disappear and on clicking Interior Tab it should be able to open the row with id as interiors. Kindly help if this is possible only with CSS, or should we use Javascript? Have tried many ways with CSS, but unable to do so.

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#construction">Construction</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="interior">Interiors</a>
  </li>

</ul>

<br>
<br>
<div id="construction">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Basic</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Standard</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Premium</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Luxury</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div id="interior">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist" id="interior">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Basic Interiors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Standard Interiors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Premium Interiors</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Luxury Interiors</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost always a bad idea to try stuff like this “using only CSS” - the accessibility of such solutions is often terrible. The class names used here look like you are using a framework like bootstrap already - so use the proper JS methods that provides for its tab handling …?

Comment: there is atrick for this by using hidden checkbox or radio and use `:check` to change the content depending on the checked checkbox

Answer (score 1):

an example of a trick to use :check pseudo with hidden radio input

```css
.tabs {
  position: relative;   
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee; 
  padding: 10px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  margin-left: -1px; 
  position: relative;
  left: 1px; 
}
.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;   
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 45px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
    <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Stuff for Tab One</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
    <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```